# Jetty WebSockets over HTTPS configured through the WebSocketServlet

Tags: java, servlets, websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have seen many examples on how to configure Jetty for HTTPS [SSL for Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362245/programatically-configure-ssl-for-jetty-9-embedded) but they all seem to utilize a separate Server class containing a `main` method for execution.  I want to execute my WebServlet as a standard servlet configured via the web.xml file.  I currently have:

```
@WebServlet
public class MonitoringServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.register(MonitoringSocket.class);
    }
}
```

Where would I place my SSL Servlet configuration code?  In the `configure` method of this Servlet?  In the `init` method?

I do understand that in this case there is no need for instantiating a `Server` object and using `.start()` and `.join`

Answer (score 1):

Servlets are just a means of producing a response to a request.

Typically a request can be from HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.1, or HTTP/2.

Using SSL/TLS for the secure part of the protocol.

*Technically speaking, HTTP isn't even required for Servlets to function.*

The protocol used to submit the request is outside of the control of the Servlet you are implementing to provide a response.

In Jetty, you'll want:

- a Server instance
- at least 1 Connector configured for SSL/TLS
- at least 1 handler assigned to the Server

  - Using servlets *without* all of the baggage of a "web application" (a "web application" typically has a `WEB-INF/web.xml`, `WEB-INF/classes`, and `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`) this would be a `ServletContextHandler`
  - Using servlets with a "web application" this would be a `WebAppContext`

This setup can come from a configured `${jetty.base}` in the `jetty-distribution` or via [embedded-jetty](/questions/tagged/embedded-jetty) use of Java to build up the server, its connectors, and its handlers.

Comment: Ok, I've seen that model before.  I do want to utilize a `WebAppContext` but I did not think I needed a Server instance.  I thought this was handled for me.  This link [Eclipse Websocket API](http://www.eclipse.org/external/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/package-summary.html) details a creation process somewhat differently.